# How to add an integer to a difference calculation and print it to the end of a line?

Tags: awk, sed

**Goal:** To print the difference between two fields separated by semicolons (`$3` and `$2`) and add an integer (`+1`) to that calculated value at the end of each line beginning with "`>`".

**Representative sample of my file:**

```
>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product
MFLLHYYLIIQVI
>lcl|ORF3_      17609   17804   (+):112:147 unnamed protein product
MQWIKDKVLIK
>lcl|ORF4_      17609   17804   (+):129:91 unnamed protein product
MFYPLYLDYLYY
>lcl|ORF5_      17609   17804   (+):90:1 unnamed protein product, partial
MIMKKEQMELLYHSHQIYFLPFPLHQNIHP
```

**Desired Output:**

```
>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:111
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product:42
MFLLHYYLIIQVI
>lcl|ORF3_      17609   17804   (+):112:147 unnamed protein product:36
MQWIKDKVLIK
>lcl|ORF4_      17609   17804   (+):129:91 unnamed protein product:39
MFYPLYLDYLYY
>lcl|ORF5_      17609   17804   (+):90:1 unnamed protein product, partial:90
MIMKKEQMELLYHSHQIYFLPFPLHQNIHP
```

---

**My current `awk` script** gets me very close by printing the difference between `$3` and `$2` at the end of each line, but does not include the `+1` addition step (*required*) and is not specific to lines beginning with "`>`", despite my attempt with `/^ *>/` (*not required*, but nice):

```
$ awk -F":" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {$4=$3-$2} $4<0 {$4=-$4} 1' file

>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:110
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR:::0
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product:41
MFLLHYYLIIQVI:::0
>lcl|ORF3_      17609   17804   (+):112:147 unnamed protein product:35
MQWIKDKVLIK:::0
>lcl|ORF4_      17609   17804   (+):129:91 unnamed protein product:38
MFYPLYLDYLYY:::0
>lcl|ORF5_      17609   17804   (+):90:1 unnamed protein product, partial:89
MIMKKEQMELLYHSHQIYFLPFPLHQNIHP:::0
```

---

**Attempts to add the integer (`+1`) to the difference calculation:**

```
$ awk -F":" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {$4+1=$3-$2} $4<0 {$4=-$4} 1' file
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =

$ awk -F":" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {$4+=1=$3-$2} $4<0 {$4=-$4} 1' file
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =

$ awk -F":" -v n=1 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {$4+n=$3-$2} $4<0 {$4=-$4} 1' file
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =
```

And although I'm not sure how to implement functions using `awk`, I think there could be some utility in using something similar to this:

```
$ function add_one (number) {
      return number + 1
  }
$ awk -F":" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {add_one($4)=$3-$2} $4<0 {$4=-$4} 1' file
```

While I have been attempting to use `awk` to solve this problem, I am interested in any solution (e.g., since I am attempting to perform this calculation line-by-line, perhaps there is a more efficient solution with `sed`?).

Comment: Upvote for well asked question which also provided your attempts to solve the problem yourself (which has been a rare occurrence lately on SO...)

Comment: Thanks David! That means a lot :) I'm trying my best to figure out how to solve my problems before posting to SO which I think really improves my ability to articulate what I am having trouble solving.

Comment: It makes a world of difference in how your questions are received. The old adage that "You never get a second chance to make a good first impression" rings true here as well `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative `awk` solution that should work on all `awk` versions:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} /^>/ {
   v3=$3+0
   diff = 1 + (v3 > $2 ? v3-$2 : $2-v3)
   $0 = $0 OFS diff
} 1' file

>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:111
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product:42
MFLLHYYLIIQVI
>lcl|ORF3_      17609   17804   (+):112:147 unnamed protein product:36
MQWIKDKVLIK
>lcl|ORF4_      17609   17804   (+):129:91 unnamed protein product:39
MFYPLYLDYLYY
>lcl|ORF5_      17609   17804   (+):90:1 unnamed protein product, partial:90
MIMKKEQMELLYHSHQIYFLPFPLHQNIHP
```

PS: Make sure to remove DOS line breaks from your input file before running this `awk`.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '/^>/{$0=$0 OFS ($6>$5?($6-$5+1):($5-$6+1))} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '/^>/{print $0,($6>$5?($6-$5+1):($5-$6+1));next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '      ##Setting field separator as : OR spaces setting OFS as colon here.
/^>/{                                    ##Checking if line starts from >
  $0=$0 OFS ($6>$5?($6-$5+1):($5-$6+1))  ##Re-setting value to current line which has current line and difference of 6th and 5th field(based on condition using ternary operators take difference as per whichever value is greater than other)
}
1                                        ##printing current line here.
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned OP has mawk and above code is not exactly working for OP so adding 1 more way of doing this here:

```
awk -v OFS=":" '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
/^>/ && match($0,/[0-9]+:[0-9]+/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,":")
  print $0,1+(arr[1]>arr[2]?(arr[1]-arr[2]):(arr[2]-arr[1]))
  next
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: It seems that both simply add a "`1`" to the end of the line. Here is an example of the what the first line looks like `>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:1`. Close though!

Comment: @Gawain, I have tested code and output is ditto same as your shown output. Could you please do check if you have control M characters in your file? Just do a `cat -v file` and see if you have them, because when I run any of above code to your post line(in your comment) I get `>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:111` for it, let me know what you see if your file.

Comment: I imagine you're right -- likely some `^M` control characters which I've encountered before. My file is 15880 lines long; is there a better way to see if there are control characters than using `cat -v file` which prints to the terminal?

Comment: @Gawain, Use like: `awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /^>/{$0=$0 OFS ($6>$5?($6-$5+1):($5-$6+1))} 1' Input_file` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Glad you were on call for this one. Looks good.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Unfortunately, I seem to be getting the same result as before with the `1` printed at the end of the line :/ . Would it be worth trying something like `dos2unix` to get rid of any control characters?

Comment: @Gawain, This should actually work, but yes if you have dos2unix then try it out first, usually people don't have it so that's why its not my 1st option :) try it out and then try my codes, these are working fine for me :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Ok, so I didn't have `dos2unix` on this machine (forgetful me), but I successfully ran `sed "s/^M//g" file` where `^M` is entered by CTRL+V then CTRL+M. After this, your first `awk` script gave me numbers at the end of the line this time (yay!), but some are negative integers and those that are negative actually have been `-1` rather than `+1` (e.g., the first line's number is `-109`, but should be `111`).

Comment: @Gawain, Please check once more with `cat -v file` I believe there could be still some control M pending? When I run my command `awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '/^>/{$0=$0 OFS ($6>$5?($6-$5+1):($5-$6+1))} 1' file` I get like: `>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product:111
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
` see there is NO negative numbers, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Gawain, Please confirm me if you see control M chars in your file still. Also I hope your actual file is same as shown one only.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Yes, just trying to search through the lines of the file for `^M` right now. It is is difficult to see if there are any among the alpha characters (i.e., `MPIICIFPQDL`), which is where I have found them before in other similar files. Yes, the sample I provided in the question is directly from my file (albeit some of the alpha lines can span multiple lines).

Comment: @Gawain, do a `tr -d '\r' < file > temp && mv temp` once and then all control M will be removed then try my codes once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Same problem as before with the negative integers and subtraction of `1`. There must be something else going on in my file. I will have to look to see how your scripts parse my file differently than my first `awk` script, because my first one worked on the whole file, just without adding `1` to each calculated number.

Comment: @Gawain, please do give me 2 exact lines where it's not working and let me retest, again codes are working fine with shown samples let me know

Comment: Well its not working for the first two lines of the sample: `>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product
MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product
MFLLHYYLIIQVI`
But another set of lines not included in the sample include: `>lcl|ORF34_     83686   84879   (-):1159:746 unnamed protein product
MDDIIEFSEFMGYKTIIVFDAYNVKNSREKVEKRKHITIVYTREHQTADSYIEKFITSLSKYDDVKVATN
DYAEQQMILGKGATRMSARELKLELDRMKEKNIGLKKDKETLSKLENIRRKR
>lcl|ORF20_     83686   84879   (-):997:1089 unnamed protein product
MSLYNYLLFGVLLYKLLENF`

Comment: @Gawain, see when I run my one of the solution, I get like `>lcl|ORF1_      17609   17804   (+):21:131 unnamed protein product MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR:111
>lcl|ORF2_      17609   17804   (+):70:111 unnamed protein product MFLLHYYLIIQVI:42
>lcl|ORF34_     83686   84879   (-):1159:746 unnamed protein product MDDIIEFSEFMGYKTIIVFDAYNVKNSREKVEKRKHITIVYTREHQTADSYIEKFITSLSKYDDVKVATN DYAEQQMILGKGATRMSARELKLELDRMKEKNIGLKKDKETLSKLENIRRKR:414
>lcl|ORF20_     83686   84879   (-):997:1089 unnamed protein product MSLYNYLLFGVLLYKLLENF:93` which looks ok to me, let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Yes, you are right on the money. Your code obviously works well. Definitely a +1 from me. Just strange that it won't work properly on my file.

Comment: @Gawain, that is what I am wondering too. How about if you create new file and then run it only with shown samples once? In your system.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Huh, oddly enough, even when I create a new file and add the sample text by copying and pasting from my example above, I get `1` at the ends (or negative integers with `-1` if I change the `$5`s to `$2`s and the `$6`s to `$3`s). May it has something to do with my machine??

Comment: @Gawain, Run this one once `awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' -v OFS=":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "field number is:"i " and field value is:" $i}}' file` by this you will see the field numbers and their values too. If you see difference between field numbers of my codes and your file then you can change them accordingly, let's try this out once :)

Comment: `field number is:1 and field value is:>lcl|ORF1_    17609   17804   (+)
field number is:2 and field value is:21
field number is:3 and field value is:131 unnamed protein product
field number is:1 and field value is:MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
field number is:1 and field value is:>lcl|ORF2_    17609   17804   (+)
field number is:2 and field value is:70
field number is:3 and field value is:111 unnamed protein product
field number is:1 and field value is:MFLLHYYLIIQVI
field number is:1 and field value is:>lcl|ORF3_     17609   17804   (+)
field number is:2 and field value is:112`

Comment: So it increments `1`, `2`, `3`, then repeats, `1`, `2`, `3`.

Comment: @Gawain, see for your one line its giving me like `field number is:1 and field value is:>lcl|ORF1_
field number is:2 and field value is:17609
field number is:3 and field value is:17804
field number is:4 and field value is:(+)
field number is:5 and field value is:21
field number is:6 and field value is:131
field number is:7 and field value is:unnamed
field number is:8 and field value is:protein
field number is:9 and field value is:product
field number is:10 and field value is:MEKVKNKFDENDIKVPFVPSSLLFNNTGNLNTMDKR
` which is correct one, looks like field separator not work in your awk

Comment: @Gawain, how about running this one once: `awk -F':| +' -v OFS=":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "field number is:"i " and field value is:" $i}}' file`? show just 1 line output. Also please do let me know your awk version `awk --version` too.

Comment: Oh dear. `awk -W version` : `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`. And 1 line of output from your last suggestions shows: `field number is:1 and field value is:>lcl|ORF1_`.

Comment: I believe my version of awk cannot understand what `[[:space:]]` is.

Comment: @Gawain, yeah. I don't have mawk with me, what output did my last comment's code given to you?

Comment: It looked _almost_ like your output (`1`-`9` matched), but where you had `10`, I had `1` again.

Comment: @Gawain, could you please check my EDIT answer and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, SUCCESS! Your latest edit - suitable for mawk - works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Gawain, cool, glad to hear. Your welcome, keep posting and keep sharing good questions/answers on great forum.

Comment: Yes, it works for me! No problems. anuhava's answer for _any_ version of `awk` is ever so slightly faster than all methods proposed and uses the same fields and field separator as my original code, so I think it makes sense to be the accepted answer. I do like the compactness of your code for newer versions of `awk` though (the ones that were working originally for you).

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^>.*:(.*):(\S*).*/echo "&:$(((\1<\2?\2-\1:\1-\2)+1))"/e' file
```

Pick out the two fields for an arithmetic expression and tag the result to the line.

N.B. The RHS of the substitution is echoed via the `e` flag which evaluates the string `&:$(((\1<\2?\2-\1:\1-\2)+1)` where `&` is the original line and `\1` and `\2` the integers. The `expr?expr:expr` is an if-then-else control flow.

Comment: For interest sake, when running these scripts on my file containing 15880 lines: anubhava's answer for any `awk` version is the fastest to execute: `real    0m0.010s`, RavinderSingh13's answer for `mawk` is second fastest: `real    0m0.014s`, and your `sed` solution works, but takes a bit of time: `real    0m9.585s`.